# How to hit the texel cache in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, gpu, gpgpu

What i'm doing is GPGPU on WebGL and I don't know the access pattern which I'd be talking about applies to general graphics and gaming programs. In our code, frequently, we come across data which needs to be summarized or reduced per output texel. A very simple example is matrix multiplication during which, for every output texel, your return a value which is a dot product of a row of one input and a column of the other input.

This has been the sore point of our performance because of not so much the computation but multiplied data access. So I've been trying to find a pattern of reads or data layouts which would expedite this operation and I have been completely unsuccessful.

I will be describing some assumptions and some schemes below. The sample code for all these are under https://github.com/jeffsaremi/webgl-experiments
Unfortunately due to size I wasn't able to use the 'snippet' feature of StackOverflow. NOTE: All examples write to console not the html page.

1. Base matmul implementation: Example: [2,3]x[3,4]->[2,4] . This produces in a simplistic form 2 textures of (w:3,h:2) and (w:4,h:3). For each output texel I will be reading along the X axis of the left texture but going along the Y axis of the right texture. (see webgl-matmul.html)
2. Assuming that GPU accesses data similar to CPU -- that is block by block -- if I read along the width of the texture I should be hitting the cache pretty often.
   For this, I'd layout both textures in a way that I'd be doing dot products of corresponding rows (along texture width) only. Example: [2,3]x[4,3]->[2,4] . Note that the data for the right texture is now transposed so that for each output texel I'd be doing a dot product of one row from the left and one row from the right. (see webgl-matmul-shared-alongX.html)
3. To ensure that the above assumption is indeed working, I created a negative test also. In this test I'd be reading along the Y axis of both left and right textures which should have the worst performance ever. Data is pre-transposed so that the results make sense. Example: [3,2]x[3,4]->[2,4]. (see webgl-matmul-shared-alongY.html).

So I ran these -- and I hope you could do as well to see -- and I found no evidence to support existence or non-existence of such caching behavior. You need to run each example a few times to get consistent results for comparison.

Then I came along this paper http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Michael_Doggett/pubs/doggett12-tc.pdf which in short claims that the GPU caches data in blocks (or tiles as I call them).

Based on this promising lead I created a version of matmul (or dot product) which uses blocks of 2x2 to do its calculation. Prior to using this of course I had to rearrange my inputs into such layout. The cost of that re-arrangement is not included in my comparison. Let's say I could do that once and run my matmul many times after. Even this scheme did not contribute anything to the performance if not taking something away. (see webgl-dotprod-tiled.html).

A this point I am completely out of ideas and any hints would be appreciated.
thanks